# Application scoped resources (JDBC) configured post deployment

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, glassfish

I'm developing a JavaEE6 application with a deployment target of GlassFish v3.1. In order to isolate instances of the application (since we may have multiple instances deployed for testing, and production, or multiple QA instances), I would like to use application scoped resources for all of the resources in the application:

- JDBC connection
- JMS resources
- Custom resources

Unfortunately, since the JDBC connection details are not static, I need to support the following sequence:

1. Deploy the WAR
2. During deployment, detect empty JDBC url/user/password, and don't perform automatic liquibase upgrade, display fallback UI warning administrator to configure JDBC settings and redeply/reload the application.
3. User configures URL in the app scoped JDBC resource
4. User reload/redeploys the application.
5. Full deployment process now includes liquibase schema updates, and full web app now available.

Unforunately, trying to load the war with empty url parameter for the JDBC connection results in a deployment failure:

```
SEVERE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
SEVERE: Exception while preparing the app
SEVERE: [PersistenceUnit: foo] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
```

Any ideas how I can get the application to deploy far enough that the app scoped JDBC connection will be present and possible to configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put in a URL to a blank or dummy database instance initially, then switch it.

You can use a class marked with @Startup to design a class that switches the URL and kicks off the Liquibase script.  That would probably also include your warning message if the app is configured for the dummy database.

@Startup examples: http://blog.eisele.net/2010/12/seven-ways-to-get-things-started-java.html

Comment: The first sentence of your answer is the root of the solution I finally found. For production release, I'm using an in-memory H2 database URL (e.g. jdbc:h2:mem:myApp) that the JPADeployer can use, Liquibase will happily upgrade, etc. Once deployed, we can configure the JDBC settings, and do a Reload in GF to get an actual deployment against our proper DB.